# In Chrome DevTools is there a way to see all page colors?

Tags: css, colors, google-chrome-devtools

In DevTools there is an option to see all page colors used on the page:

[image: DevTools color picker]

Is it possible to also see usages of those colors or to export them in some format?

Web developer tools addon has an option to see color information of the page which looks like:

[image: Web developer tools color info]

I was hoping for something similar in DevTools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS Overview in devtools to do this
for this go to dev tools settings and enable CSS Overview, reload deve tools then a new tab should popup with all the css information in it

Comment: Wow! Exactly what I was needed. Nice experiment :)